# Bindings inside lazy prime number generator function in Clojure

Tags: clojure, lazy-evaluation, primes, seq

I have implemented a lazy prime number generator (nextprime returns the next prime starting from the number passed):

```
(defn allprimes
    ([] (allprimes 2))
    ([x] (lazy-seq (cons (nextprime x) (allprimes (nextprime x))))))
```

Let's assume nextprime is a costly function, in order not to execute it twice I have tried binding it to a symbol:

```
(defn allprimes
    ([] (allprimes 2))
    ([x] (let [next (nextprime x)]
        (cons next (lazy-seq (allprimes (next)))))))
```

But this does not work (java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn). Why?

Also, is there any difference between (cons n (lazy-seq ...)) and (lazy-seq (cons n ...)) ?

edit: thanks Kyle for pointing the error in the first question. If parentheses are removed from next, it works.

Comment: `next` is in function position. Try removing the parens - `(allprimes next)`

Comment: Thanks, first question is closed... I feel so dumb!

Comment: Also take a look at `iterate` which constructs a lazy seq for you - `(def allprimes (iterate nextprime 2))`

Comment: it should have been `(cons x (allprimes (nextprime x)))` anyway, no need for the `let`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have extra parenthesis around `(next)` : `next` is then called as a function `IFn` though `next` is a `Long`...

For your second question, the las example in [clojure doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq) gives details on the difference between the 2 solutions.

Roughly `(cons n (lazy-seq ...))` will always evaluate `n`, even if it is not consumed, and `(lazy-seq (cons n ...))` is fully lazy. It can matter if `n` is not just a number but some function that may be computation intensive.